# Laravel display data from database table get() and first() methods

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-7

I want to display data on view file from database table using get()...and i get this error ''Property [agent_name] does not exist on this collection instance''...but if i change the method to first() i get the unexpected output of first recorded data in a table.

this is my function in MiniStatementController

```
  public function ministatements($id)
    {
      
        $mini_reports = DB::table('mini_statements')->where('user_id',$id)->get();
        $user = User::where('id',$id)->first();
 
        return view('vendor/voyager/reports/view_user_mini_statements')->with('mini_reports',$mini_reports)->with('user',$user);

        
    }
```

And this is my view file view_user_ministatements.blade.php

```
@extends('voyager::master')




@section('page_header')
    <div class="container-fluid">
      
    </div>
@stop

@section('content')

    <div class="page-content browse container-fluid">
        @include('voyager::alerts')
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="container">

                    <table class="table table-striped mt-5">
                        <thead>
                          <tr>
                            <th scope="col">#</th>
                            <th scope="col">Agent Name</th>
                            <th scope="col">Action</th>
                            <th scope="col">Amount</th>
                            <th scope="col">Time</th>
                          </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                         @if (is_array($mini_reports) || is_object($mini_reports))
                          @foreach ($mini_reports as $mini_report)    
                            <tr>
                              <th scope="row">1</th>
                              <td>{{$mini_reports->agent_name}}</td>
                              <td>{{\App\Action::where('id',$mini_reports->action)->first()->action_name}}</td>
                              <td>{{$mini_reports->amount}}</td>
                              <td>{{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($mini_reports->created_at)->diffForHumans() }}</td>
                            </tr>
                          @endforeach
                          @endif
                        </tbody>
                      </table>
            
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

     
@stop
```

How i routed in web.php file

Route::get('/{id}/{name}/view_user_mini_statements', 'MinistatementController@ministatements');

Any help please...Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get returns an array of object, so you need to use index to get it.

The first() method will return only one record, while the get() method will return an array of records that you can loop over.

Comment: Thanks for the answer it seems to be working it just iterate or repeat first record multiple times not showing all the records that i need to show...can you elaborate more on how to do it properly...thanks again

Comment: Good to hear, kindly mark it as correct answer

Comment: use this option $mini_report->agent_name while printing the result

Comment: Thats great to hear, if it solves your problem pls mark this as correct answer.